# diffrence between 'its' and "it's" as possevsive pronoun

Tags: meaning

Would to tell me  difference between the *its*
and *it's* please

Answer (score -1):

It's—a contraction, which is means **it is**. *It is/It's* said that *it is/it's* (see what I did there?) not to be used in formal writing along with *he's*, *she's*, etc.

Its—the 3rd-person possessive pronoun of **it**. "When it comes to the Samsung Galaxy Note 4, *its* battery sucks as it can only last up to a day compare to *its* successor, the Samsung Galaxy Note 5." (This is something that I'd with my Note 4 and my sister's Note 5.)

Don't get confused to the two, 'cause one is a pronoun—and the other isn't. I hope this clears it up :)

Comment: What makes you think only "its" is a pronoun and not the other/"it"? *It* can be a [personal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-personal-i-me-you-him-it-they-etc) or [impersonal](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/impersonal-pronoun). *It* is still a pronoun in the contracted "it's", but "it's" as a whole is generally referred to as an elision.

Comment: Take a look at a list of pronouns, can thou even see "it's", "he's", "you've", and the likes on it? Absolutely not. (I know how to use "thou" and its buddies, but I like to make it feel like it can fit in the English today since I have love on those.) Thus, I say that "it's" is a contraction and not a pronoun itself, albeit the pronoun "it" is in it.

Comment: What are you even on about? Thou is an archaic pronoun and is not an elision/contraction

Comment: I'm using "thou" to address thee, aeasking. It's of course nowhere related to elision/contraction.

Comment: "Can thou" is a great demo of how not to use *thou* forms. Try *cannest* or *canst* for short.